# How to create unique key that can be maintained through exports and imports

Tags: mysql, import, export, unique, auto-increment

I want to create 3 tables:

1. categories
2. items
3. items within categories

The **categories** and **items** records need to have unique keys, so I had planned to create them with an auto-increment integer field called RecordID.

The "**items within categories**" records will basically have the following fields to match items to categories: item_RecordID, category_RecordID.

However, I want to be able to rebuild these tables on multiple installations through flexible import/export utilities that I build myself. I don't trust auto-increment to keep the RecordID fields the same through multiple installations.

What is the best way to maintain consistency of the RecordID fields? Should I create a duplicate RecordID field as I write each **items** and **categories** record, then use that duplicate in the "**items within categories**" table? Or is there a more straightforward or more efficient way to do this?

This is a simple question. I apologize if I got any terminology wrong - I am relatively new to MySQL and php. (Background is Microsoft Access, ASP, and ecommerce technologies that already have import/export set up.)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is one of your concerns, that your different systems will generate conflicting rows because of duplicate RecordID's? Did you look into [UUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)?

Comment: I'll look at the UUIDs article. My main concern is that I am using these cross-reference one-to-many (or possibly many-to-many) tables to relate data. Those relationships need to be maintained across systems. The "items within categories" table needs to have reliable data. In the past, I have not had to import/export data, so the auto-incremented values were reliable enough. Those sites had minimal content & updates. Now I need to work across systems with complex export/import requirements, initially bc I am making a lot of changes to the systems & I don't want to redo/fix my data every time.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is FOREIGN KEYs. Whithout it you cannot trust on consistency on multiple tables and especially on AUTO INCREMENTs. A-I can sometimes change in some situations (if you play with backup/delete/restore or replication).

Comment: Thank you. I will check them out.